# How to send a date using Dynamics 4.0 web services with CrmDateTime type

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I have a crmdatetime field on a custom field in Dynamics 4.0.  I'm using the webservice to send the date over.  Unfortunately, the date is not getting saved.  Any thoughts:

```
            CrmDateTime crmstartdate = new CrmDateTime();
            CrmDateTime crmstartDate = new CrmDateTime();
            crmstartdate.date = System.Convert.ToString(startingdate);
            CrmDateTime crmendDate = new CrmDateTime();
            crmendDate.date = System.Convert.ToString(endingdate);
            ev.new_startingdate = crmstartdate;
            ev.new_endingdate = crmendDate;
            Guid eventid=util.service.Create(ev);
```

So even though I'm sending the date over, it isn't being saved.

Thoughts about what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

It looks your question is similar to [this one](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb959840.aspx). Take a look at [this function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb959840.aspx)